# Jquery não monta data corretamente

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz isso e a msg é: **Data Inválida**. Acho que é porque tudo virou string. Como eu faço para trazer somente a parte numérica na data? Aliás, falo isso, porque não consigo retornar uma data no nosso formato dentro do *jQuery*. No ***alert()*** dá **Data Inválida**.

```
var dtCadastro = data.agendamento.DataCadastro.substring(6, data.agendamento.DataCadastro.length - 2);
var dtAgendanmento = data.agendamento.DataAgendamento.substring(6, data.agendamento.DataAgendamento.length - 2);
var dtVisita = data.agendamento.DataVisita.substring(6, data.agendamento.DataVisita.length - 2);

var dt = new Date(dtCadastro);

alert(dt);

var dtCadastro = (Date)(data.agendamento.DataCadastro.substring(6, data.agendamento.DataCadastro.length - 2));
```

Este foi o cast que fiz, mas a data vem tipo:

```
Mon Jun 16 2014 14:24:45 GMT....
```

Gostaria de apenas um: 16/06/2014, sem a parte hora

Comment: Fiz um cast pada Date, aí consigo trazer a data, mas vem num formato quase que extenso e gostaria que fosse assim: dd/MM/yyyy somente. Vou editar o post para mostrar o cast

Comment: É mais fácil você formatar a data no C#. Tem o trecho de código C# que retorna o valor para que eu possa ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var x = "/Date(1402369200000)/";
var re = /-?\d+/; 
var m = re.exec(x); 
var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0], 10));
console.log(d);

// output: Tue Jun 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

**Explicação**

1. `x` recebe a data no formato string (DateTime do C# serializado em json, por exemplo);
2. `re` é o padrão em expressão regular para separar os números em um grupo (no caso o grupo na posição `0` do vetor `m`);
3. `m` é o vetor com o resultado do reconhecimento do padrão `re` (o que o regex reconhece);
4. `m[0]` é o valor, em epoch da data;
5. `parseInt` converte para inteiro na base 10;
6. `d` é a sua nova data.

**Em 1 linha**

```
var d = new Date(parseInt(/-?\d+/.exec("/Date(1402369200000)/")[0], 10));
console.log(d);
```

**Para formatar**

- `d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getFullYear() -> "10/6/2014"`
- `d.toDateString() -> "Tue Jun 10 2014"`
- `d.toLocaleDateString() -> "10/6/2014"`

**Exemplo com DataCadastro**

```
function getFormattedDate(date){
 var re = /-?\d+/; 
 var m = re.exec(date); 
 var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0], 10));
 return d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
}

var dCad = getFormattedDate(data.agendamento.DataCadastro);
console.log(dCad);
```

Comment: Para formatar você pode utilizar: d.toLocaleDateString(). Vai retornar: '10/6/2014'. Para adicionar hora, você usa: d.toLocaleString(). Ou você pode formatar do jeito que precisar com: d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear()

Comment: Fiz assim, Maia e formatou. Mas agora os três campos datas estão vindo com a mesma data todos(16/05/2014) e essa data nem existe em meu BD. Quando dou um break point no controller e vejo a data que está vindo, vem três datas diferentes e são as datas corretas, mas depois que eu pego no jquery via json, aí vem essa data incorreta e preenche todas as datas com esse valor(incorreto).

Comment: O melhor seria você enviar a data já formatada em C# (como o Joao Paulo sugeriu). Para os casos onde as datas estão erradas, pode ser que algumas variáveis esteja sendo aplicadas de forma errada. Preciso ver mais código para saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Veja o exemplo com DataCadastro que coloquei. Talvez ajude você.

Comment: Veja só, conforme eu disse no C# está ok, as datas são as válidas que existem no BD. Quando serializo e pego no jquery e faço essas formatações é zoa tudo.

Comment: Resolveu maia de acordo com a sua última resposta. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

É mais fácil você formatar a data no C#.

Exemplo: String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", VariavelDaData);

Comment: No C# ela está correta. A questão é na serelização para o json e pegar no jquery. Mas resolvi com o exemplo do maia, criando uma função para limpar a "data suja" e depois pegá-la na função principal.